# How to constrain F# function argument to PropertyGet?

Tags: f#

I have some code that takes an expression and uses it just fine; trouble is, my constraint that the expression passed is a PropertyGet is a run-time constraint, not compile time:

```
member x.f(propertyExpr) =
    match propertyExpr with
    | PropertyGet(_, propOrValInfo, _) -> () // do something
    | _ -> failwith "Unexpected expression type; needs PropertyGet"
```

What I'd really like is to constrain the type of the expression at compile time. The following illustrates my intent:

```
member x.f(propertyExpr: Expr.PropertyGet) =
    () // do something
```

This does not compile, of course. The desired attributes are: a compile-time check--it's safer, and I have fewer exceptions to worry about. But how to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible to do. Discriminated Unions in F#, even though they are compiled down into a class hierarchy, don't allow to use the cases as proper types. In Scala the equivalent is possible to do with case classes, but I believe none of the ML-derived languages allow that.